# Android Multiple JSON parsing for image downloading (best practice needed)

Tags: android, json, backend

So, my application stands from two screens.
**MainScreen** download a list items (list.json) and display the result in a ListView (done). 
Then, when the user push on an item, I need to display a **details screen**, where I write more details about the product (done). 
My problem is the following: all item on the main screen have to display an image, but there is no URL for the image at this point. I have only the detailsURL for a second JSON file (this is containing the imageURL itself).

At the moment, when I press on an item I can start download the detailsURL and gain access to the imageURL. My problem with this approach, I'm not able to download the image on the main screen. What is the best practice in this case?

My thoughts so far:

- Downloading the detailsURL and fetch the imageURL, when the user scrolling on the list. This is a waste of network communication and memory.
- Displaying the images only for the items, where the user already pressed for details page. This is very very beginner approach I would say.

I'm looking forward to see your answer, what is the best practice in this case? 
(I don't have the chance to chance the backend structure.)

Comment: After a restart. Is all downloaded again? Or did you save the data for reuse?

Comment: Downloading the list if the internet is available & clear the cache. But if there is no connection, than load everything back from the cache.

Comment: Make a service which downloads all in the backgound. As soon as you know an image url start a thread to download the image. After download done send a broadcast to main activity to load that specific image (if it is in view).

Comment: But you could also just start downloading the details and then the image in getView(). That is no network waste i think. If you had the url you would start the image download in getView() too. Only now it's a two step process.